# Is there a way to save and restore QGIS's most recently used (MRU) list of maps in File menu?

Tags: qgis-3

I often need to use a lot of QGIS maps. Sometimes, some needed maps get flushed out of the list in the `File -> Open -> Recent` menu as I experiment with other maps. I sometimes don't remember where those maps are stored on the disk. To keep the most needed maps close at hand:

*Is there a way to use QGIS (QGIS 3) itself to export the MRU (most recently used) list to a text file and then restore it to QGIS when the MRU list is "out of shape"?*

*If this isn't possible directly, can it be programmed to work somehow via pyqgis?*

Answer (score 4):

MRU projects are stored in QGIS' global settings in the user profile.

Outside of QGIS, you can find them in the `QGIS3.ini` file which is located wherever QGIS stores its profile information. At the present time, each MRU project is stored in a block of entries starting with `recentProjects\n\...` where n is the number of the entry in the MRU.

Therefore, for instance under Windows you could do the following at the CMD prompt or batch file:

```
cd %userprofile%\AppData\roaming\qgis\qgis3\profiles\default\qgis
findstr "recentProjects.*path" QGIS3.ini > mrulist.txt
```

This would save the MRU paths in a file called `mrulist.txt`.
The entries each have a prefix of `recentProjects\1\path=`.

If you wanted to change the MRU list you could, though then you should also store and when needed replace the corresponding `\n\title=` and `\n\crs=`, via a cmd/shell script or Python run outside QGIS.

This is undocumented and so subject to change, ymmv, and at your own risk. In particular, definitely save a backup of your `QGIS3.ini` file before mucking with it.

You can also access these as items inside QGIS using `Settings / Options / Advanced Settings` (clicking the button that you'll be careful), under `UI / Recent projects`, where you could edit them one by one in a dialog box.

Finally, this all means that you can also manipulate them in PyQGIS as a `QgsSettings` object. See https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/settings.html for instructions for both reading and writing. Since these settings are in the `UI` group, you can access them as

```py
s=QgsSettings()
s.value('UI/recentProjects/1/path')
```

To automate, you should probably back up and then restore not only the `/path` but also the `/title` and `/crs` and likely also `previewImage` and `pin` thought haven't tried it.